# farmville clone

Tags: apache-flex, flash, frameworks

is there any opensource flex or flash code to accommodate a starting point for a game like farm-ville or alike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about a system to let you build games like Farm Ville with Flash FLEX ActionScript 3 there's one my friend... and it's name is the "Push Button Engine".

Take a look at it in:

http://pushbuttonengine.com/

Let me know if it was what you were looking for!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Many Facebook games (including [Social City](http://www.facebook.com/SocialCity)) use code from [Pushbutton Labs](http://pushbuttonlabs.com/). The Pushbutton Engine is a set of Flash libraries that you can pick and choose from.

Another choice is [OpenSpace](http://www.openspace-engine.com/), but I haven't personally used that one.

Comment: have u used pushbutton components urself?